# How to tell which Ubuntu package a tool is in

Tags: ubuntu, apt

As a concrete example I want to be able to take a particular tool that isn't installed (say nslookup) and be able to tell which package I need to install when the following fails:

```
apt-get install nslookup
E: Unable to locate package nslookup
```

Obviously I can google to find the answer for a specific package (dnsutils) but I want to know how to find it myself.

Comment: this is quick and dirty apt-cache search nslookup

Comment: apt-cache only searches the descriptions.  I was looking for specific file, ErikA pointed out: apt-file search FOO

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There are two ways I know of to do this:

```
host ~ # apt-file update
host ~ # apt-file search nslookup
dnsutils: /usr/bin/nslookup
dnsutils: /usr/share/man/man1/nslookup.1.gz
gajim: /usr/share/gajim/src/common/nslookup.py
kaptain: /usr/share/kaptain/nslookup.kaptn
kvirc2-data: /usr/share/kvirc2/help/en/nslookup.kvihelp
libgnet2.0-0: /usr/share/doc/libgnet2.0-0/examples/dnslookup.c.gz
manpages-ja: /usr/share/man/ja/man8/nslookup.8.gz
procmail-lib: /usr/share/procmail-lib/pm-janslookup.rc
rbot: /usr/share/rbot/plugins/nslookup.rb
scrollz: /usr/share/scrollz/help/nslookup
zsh: /usr/share/zsh/4.3.4/functions/Completion/Unix/_nslookup
zsh: /usr/share/zsh/4.3.4/functions/Misc/nslookup
zsh-beta: /usr/share/zsh-beta/functions/Completion/Unix/_nslookup
zsh-beta: /usr/share/zsh-beta/functions/Misc/nslookup
```

and...

```
host ~ # apt-cache search nslookup
host - utility for querying DNS servers
dnsutils - Clients provided with BIND
```

Comment: `apt-cache` only searches the packages you already have installed, while `apt-file` searches ALL packages in your `sources.list`, including packages that aren't installed. So in this case, `apt-file` is the one to use.

Comment: @Steven, I'm going to have to disagree with that. I just did a test search for "vlc" on my ubuntu VPS using apt-cache, and it showed all of the vlc-related packages, none of which I have installed.

Comment: @Steven Monai, that isn't true.  `apt-cache` looks at package descriptions (searches `/var/lib/apt/lists/*_Packages`).  Having something installed doesn't matter.  The package descriptions don't include a list of the files.  I agree that `apt-file` is probably the tool to use, if opening a web browser isn't an option.

Comment: There's also auto-apt, as an alternative to apt-file. I don't have a strong preference. auto-apt can listen on failed exec calls, which can be useful when running a configure script that does feature detection.

Comment: @EricA, Zoredache: I stand corrected. Let me restate: If you need to know which uninstalled package contains a particular file (e.g. `/usr/bin/nslookup`), then use `apt-file`. If you only want to search the package names and descriptions, then `apt-cache` works just fine.

Comment: well, bummer i m in docker, `#apt-file update
bash: apt-file: command not found`

Comment: but: `#apt-get install dnsutils ...............Fetched 603 kB in 0s (1461 kB/s) ....Unpacking ....done`

Answer (score 3):

Do you have `command-not-found` installed?

Just type the command in bash or zsh and it will tell you which package has it, and if you need to enable non-main repos or fix your PATH. Or call `command-not-found $command_name`.

Or you could go to http://packages.ubuntu.com/file:bin/nslookup , but that defaults to karmic packages.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to do this from the command line?  I usually just do a search on http://packages.ubuntu.com/ (or [packages.debian.org](http://packages.debian.org)) when I am looking for packages.

Answer (score 0):

[Ubuntu's online repository browser](http://packages.ubuntu.com/) has "Search the contents of packages" feature.
AFAIK, it's not implemented in apt-get/aptitude, but in the most cases you will be satisfied with "apt-get search" when searching for a package containing a similarly named program.